# how to use nlapiSetFieldMandatory(fieldname,bool) in netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Can someone help me to use this function nlapiSetFieldMandatory(fieldname,bool). I try change the field from mandatory to non mandatory using this function. but it didn't work. My friend told me. The operation works in the debugger and also for custom fields.  However, because the field im using to change is an system field there is an internal guard call that blocks the change.   When you are in the debugger it is treated as "internal". Can some one help me or explained this. Appreciate the help. By the way in using javascripts client script. Thank you,

Comment: I solved this problem by reading the code of nlapiSetFieldMandatory function(). When you run the code on the console you will get error. I trace the error of this function and overwrite the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is an undocumented method, so I am not sure it is officially supported by NetSuite. Many of the Field API methods do not work client-side because the `nlobjField` objects they operate on are *supposed* to be read-only. Instead of doing this in a Client Script, try a User Event script. Instead of using `nlapiSetFieldMandatory`, use `nlapiGetField('yourfieldid').setMandatory(true)`

If the field should always be mandatory, instead of a script you can simply customize the form and make your custom form the Preferred one for all roles.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my boss doesn't allowed me to create a user event. Only client script

Answer (score -1):

If it is a standard field then I would suggest to use workflow. Worlfow can set a field to Mandatory or Non-Mandatory on field edit which cannot be done in client script because nlobjField is read only.

Comment: are you saying that on my client script its impossible to change the field from mandatory to non mandatory? Or do you have an alternative ways except to use workflow?

Comment: It is not possible using client script the alternate way is via workflow provided that you are setting the field as mandatory/non mandatory on custom form/standard form.

Comment: You might want to explore the Set Field Mandatory workflow action